# Error "The action you have requested is invalid" while fetching data via AJAX in EE 2.7.2

Tags: forms, ajax, xid, secure

I try to implement infinite scrolling in EE 2.7.2.

There are 2 templates: "infinite_scrolling_main" and "infinite_scrolling_embed". There are no forms in any of these two templates. AJAX call from the page outputted by template "infinite_scrolling_main" should fetch the data outputted by template "infinite_scrolling_embed".

This setting worked correctly prior to EE 2.7. But after upgrade to 2.7.2 any AJAX call outputs error message "The action you have requested is invalid" instead of proper data.

This issue seems to be related to XID handling. If I set

```
$config['secure_forms'] = "n";
```

AJAX works correctly.

What should be done to keep secure forms and to be able to fetch data via AJAX in EE2.7.2?

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the XID validation by making a GET request instead of a POST request. XID validation only occurs when secure_forms is `y` and the `$_POST` array is not empty.

Or you can generate a valid XID hash by using `{XID_HASH}` in your template. Maybe something like:

```
<body data-xid="{XID_HASH}">

<script>
$.post(
  'site/inifinite_scroll_ajax',
  {
    XID: $('body').data('xid')
  },
  function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // Update the XID with a fresh one from the response headers
    $('body').data('xid', jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-EEXID'));

    // Do whatever you want with data
  }
);
</script>
```

In the response, EE will send along a fresh XID hash in a custom HTTP header, X-EEXID. You can use that new hash for the next request. In the callback in my example, it updates the xid stored in the body data-xid attribute with the fresh hash.

Comment: But there is some issues relevant to solution you proposed.
XID handling in EE2.7.2 requires that along each AJAX request a valid XID should be sent. This means that for each new request the earlier request should be completed (earlier request is the source of XID string) and completed successfully. 
But what should be done if request fails and should be repeated or request should be canceled and a new request should be executed immediately after canceling?

Comment: Please check my updated answer ↑

Comment: Thanks, Rob, for your help.

It is strange, but it seems that there is no variable 'X-EEXID' inside response headers. How it might be?

Comment: Did you inspect the response headers in Chrome dev tools or Charles and see if that header is in the response?

Comment: Yes, I inspected responce headers in Chrome javascript console and in Firefox Firebug, and found that there is no variable 'X-EEXID'. 

I inspected [this example][1] and [this][2].


  [1]: http://antiquityillustrated.com/index.php/technical/pi_infinite_scroll_more_link_used
  [2]: http://antiquityillustrated.com/index.php/technical/pi_ajax_login_simple

Comment: Check line 137 of EE_Security.php, that's where the X-EEXID header gets set. Maybe something is breaking there? Not ruling out an EE bug, since this XID behavior is fairly new.

Comment: Thank you Rob.

I found that the variable X-EEXID was not sent in response headers because my AJAX script was not sending X_REQUESTED_WITH variable in request headers.

Comment: Great. Does it work now?